# How to see what Sphinx Indexes terms as?

Tags: sphinx

I have done a series of regexp_filter and wordforms and am getting unexpected results, i.e. not getting records back I expect to with a query. I am using SphinxQL called from Navicat MySql editor. Is there a way I can ask it to display the term is has indexed each (or a given) record as so I can get a better idea of what I actually indexed as after all my transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Well can use `SHOW PLAN`, to see the decomposed QUERY string. That should show the result of all the regex_filters, wordforms, charset_table etc.

(but its running on the query itself, which has all the extended syntax, so its not an exact emulation on how document text will be parsed and indexed. )

- There is also the `--fold` option for `indextool`, which potentially may help. Not tried it.